# How do i make the bot to add reaction to every message send in a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Ive been trying to make this work but the bot won't react to messages in that specific channel.

the code:

```
from nextcord.ext import commands

class React(commands.Cog, name="React"):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_send(self, message):
        channel = 925073325066178570
        if message.channel.id == channel:
            await message.add_reaction("⬆️")

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(React(bot))
```

there is no error detected by the code editor.

Comment: Maybe `message.channel.id` is not equal to 925073325066178570?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it is equal to 925073325066178570 tho

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the channel id of the specific channel i want the bot to react messages in it is 925073325066178570. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What happens if you change `if message.channel.id == channel:` to `if True:`?

Comment: and wdym if true: @mkrieger1 im quite new to coding sry for the trouble

Comment: Go to your text editor, delete `message.channel.id == channel` and type `True` instead.

Comment: @mkrieger1 like this?
```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_send(self, message):
        channel = 925073325066178570
        if True:
            await message.add_reaction("⬆️")
            print(message.channel.id)
```

Comment: Yes. i.e., the check for the channel id is just skipped.

Comment: @mkrieger1 nothing happened too

Comment: How do you know that your code is executed at all?

Comment: @mkrieger1 vcs has a run code option and i ran the code in my main file just like i did to start my bot

Comment: `on_message_send` is not an event in nextcord. The correct name for the event is `on_message`

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs and mkrieger turns out that it is because of on_message_send, sorry for troubling yall

Answer (score -1):

```
from nextcord.ext import commands

class React(commands.Cog, name="React"):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_send(self, message):
        channel = 925073325066178570
        if message.channel.id == channel:
            await message.add_reaction("⬆️")

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(React(bot))
```

How I think I would do it is:

```
import discord
bot=Client()
@bot.event
async def on_message(message)
    channel=('maybe try a name?')
    if message.channel==channel:
        message.add_reaction('#')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Downvoted because no explanation is given, code has errors and doesn't stick to the original intent of the OP, who is using a `Cog`

Comment: It's the same thing in better words, where exactly is the explanation needed?

Comment: It's good to add an explanation so people know where they went wrong, instead of just giving them code to copy-paste. There's also an error with `bot=Client()` (You imported the discord module, not discord.Client). OP is using a Cog, and the code in this answer is not in a `Cog`. OP is using nextcord, and this answer provides a solution with discord.py. That's why I downvoted. Please see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try and make it

```py
channel = self.bot.fetch_channel(925073325066178570) #getting from API
```

or

```py
channel = self.bot.get_channel(925073325066178570) # getting channel from cache
```

- remember you had defined the channel object as a channel ID.

2. change the `on_message_send` to `on_message` then everything should work, but please reply if there is any problem you get.

Comment: You would have to `await` the `fetch_channel` method.

Comment: I mean, I could just edit it tbh, the downvote seems a bit much since it was just that 1 mistake + you will probably get a Courotine error therefore you will know that the `await` is required as it is also basic python.

Comment: I downvoted because 1. The error: Answers should be accurate. 2. The first part of the answer does not have any relevance to the question, nor does it even work: you'd be comparing an id to a channel object. 3. The OP had already fixed their issue in the comments, so this answer does not really contribute much.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(Your channel ID)
    if message.channel.id == channel:
        await message.add_reaction("⬆️")
```

Comment: Why did the code in the question not work?